# Rephrase the phrase

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What does it mean? Can anyone rephrase this phrase?

> I did this because this song was love at first listen to me.

Does it mean or don't?:

I did it because this song was love for me when I first listened.

Comment: I don't know exactly why you were down voted, but here are a couple suggestions. Don't ask for a "rephrasing". Instead, focus on something specific you don't understand, like a word or grammar point. Also, include the context. What is the source? Who said this and why was it said? You can [edit] your post to make clarifications.  See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Answer (score 0):

> I did it because I fell in love with the song the first time I heard
>   it.

Or more simply

> I did it because I love the song.